# Error: [Immer] The plugin for 'MapSet' has not been loaded into Immer. To enable the plugin, import and call `enableMapSet()`

Tags: vuejs3, aws-amplify, datastore

I'm getting this cryptic error when using Vue3 with Amplify and the Amplify DataStore, while attempting to do something simple that used to work:  setting the value of a ref in an event handler.

My guess is that some kind of dependency problem has arisen, but I don't know anything about Immer or what's going wrong now. Searching the web isn't giving me an answer, which usually means that I f***'d up, but maybe it's not me this time. :D  Thanks for your help!

I'm going to keep digging at this, and hopefully solve my own problem, but for now, here's the stacktrace.

```
immer.esm.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: [Immer] The plugin for 'MapSet' has not been loaded into Immer. To enable the plugin, import and call `enableMapSet()` when initializing your application.
    at n (immer.esm.js:1:210)
    at b (immer.esm.js:1:2048)
    at R (immer.esm.js:1:3550)
    at Object.get (immer.esm.js:1:14257)
    at Function.entries (<anonymous>)
    at datastore.js:556:1
    at produce (immer.esm.js:1:16032)
    at Model.copyOf (datastore.js:545:32)
    at traverseModel (util.js:130:1)
    at IndexedDBAdapter.<anonymous> (IndexedDBAdapter.js:319:56)
    at step (tslib.es6.js:100:1)
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:81:46)
    at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js:71:43)
```

Answer (score 0):

Derp.  I was accessing the `ref` without `value`
...  O.o